How is the S Parameter Derived for a 2-Port Shunt Through Network?
I’m trying to understand this 2-port shunt through network but have been struggling for a few hours. I’m a little confused on why we need to use this setup to measure a small DUT (device under test) impedance for when the impedance could be very small. Why do we need a 2-port network? How is the S21 transmission parameter being calculated and how does that tell us something about the DUT impedance? I also wanted to understand how this works practically. Thank you!


If your goal is just to find the value of R, you could indeed treat the device as a one-port and only measure its reflection characteristic.
But the goal in presenting the material is probably more to teach you to think about 2-port parameters and how they relate to the network inside the 2-port. You won't normally measure such simple devices as the "shunt through" but you need to learn to analyze simple networks before you start looking at more complex ones.
To answer your specific questions,

How is the S21 transmission parameter being calculated

When they wrote
$$S_{21} = \frac{V_2+I_2R_0}{V_1+I_1R_0}$$
they were just rewriting the definition of \$S_{21}\$, \$S_{21}=\frac{v_{a2}}{v_{a1}}\$ (where \$v_a1\$ is the voltage associated with the forward travelling wave at port 1 and \$v_a2\$ is the voltage associated with the forward travelling wave at port 2.
They've skipped a few steps in calculating it from some easier to understand representation, but that's all they've done.

how does that tell us something about the DUT impedance?

You have an expression for \$S_{21}\$ as a function of \$R\$. So if you know \$S_{21}\$ you can invert the equation and find \$R\$.
But I don't think that was the point of the exercise. The exercise is about (a very simple case of) going the other way --- when you know the network and want to figure out what the S-parameters will be.

I see what you mean, I’ve been stuck on trying to figure out the 2-port approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Okay, that makes sense. I’ve been struggling to come up with the expression they have for S21 (V2/V1). Could you guide me through the KCL/KVL to derive that?
